# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object InjectFrom(System.Object, System.Object[])'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following code, which works fine & as expected:

```
return profileEntities.Select(x => (ProfileDTO)new ProfileDTO()
        {
            Localizations = new List<ProfileLocalizationDTO>()
        }
        .InjectFrom(x)).ToList();
```

However, I want to take it one step further, and populate `Localizations` with values from a repo, as so:

```
return profileEntities.Select(x => (ProfileDTO)new ProfileDTO()
        {
            Localizations = _repoProfileLocalization
                                .Query(y => y.ProfileId == x.Id)
                                .Select(y => (ProfileLocalizationDTO)new ProfileLocalizationDTO().InjectFrom(y))
                                .ToList()
        }
        .InjectFrom(x)).ToList();
```

This throws the error

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'System.Object InjectFrom(System.Object, System.Object[])' method, and
>   this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second version you will have to call `AsEnumerable()` inside your `Select` to tell clr that the method `InjectFrom` will be executed in memory.

```
return profileEntities.Select(x => (ProfileDTO)new ProfileDTO()
    {
      Localizations = _repoProfileLocalization
                          .Query(y => y.ProfileId == x.Id)
                          .AsEnumerable()
                          .Select(y => (ProfileLocalizationDTO)new ProfileLocalizationDTO()
                                      .InjectFrom(y))
                          .ToList()
    }
    .InjectFrom(x)).ToList();
```

In your first example because you instantiate a generic List inside the select, you will have all the results in memory after the select, because Linq can't execute that on the database. In the second example, Linq is still trying to do everything on the database in the select, but then you call a method which can't be translated to sql and you get the error.

Comment: That worked! Thanks!